# Play individual wav files with jQuery mouseenter

Tags: jquery, function, loops

I'm storing some jQuery code inside an object and need to play a specific local audio file using `.mouseenter`. I have 16 different files stored locally and each file has the same name as the button id. For example the sound file "work_it.wav" would play for `<button id="work_it" class="buttons" type="button" name="button">Work It</button>`. There's no need to stop the audio as each file is only 2-3s long.

I'd like to loop through somehow in my "playSound" function. My code is below any help is appreciated.

```
var daftP = daftP || {};

daftP.setup = function() {
  this.$audio = $('#sounds');
  this.$audio = $('audio');
  this.$heads = $('.buttons');
  this.colorChange();
};

daftP.colorChange = function() {
  this.$heads.each(function() {
    $(this).on('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/helmet2.png)');
      this.playSound();
    });
    $(this).on('mouseout', function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/helmet1.png)');
    });
  });
};

daftP.playSound = function() {

};

$(daftP.setup.bind(daftP));
```